# Electron - openShowDialog is undefined

Tags: javascript, electron

I am using Electron ,I have made a custom titlebar with a div which unhides 2 divs,
I want one of these divs(labeld "open") to open a file manager
This can be done using 
`shell.showItemInFolder(--dirname);`
But the problem is that i cannot retrieve any data from this method , another way is to use Dialog in electron
 `const{dialog} = require('electron');`
I treid is to write this 
`console.log(dialog.openShowDialog({properties:['openFile']}));`
This (according to some youtube videos i watched) should open a file manager and if i select a file through this , it should log a pending promise.But i get an error
`cannot get the property 'showOpenDialog'of undefined`

```
const{dialog} = require('electron');
function openFS(){
    win.openDevTools();
    console.log(dialog.showOpenDialog({properties:['openFile']}));
}
```

This openFS function is called on the click of the div mentioned above.
How do i get around?

Answer (score 0):

> cannot get the property 'showOpenDialog'of undefined

That error indicates that `dialog` is undefined. If you are executing this code in the render process, then you are not importing the `dialog` module correctly – it needs to be accessed through `remote` (assuming you have specified `nodeIntegration: true` for the renderer). Personally, I handle all dialog calls in the main process but that's a matter of choice.

```
const {dialog} = require('electron').remote
```

**HOWEVER . .**    [the remote module is deprecated](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/breaking-changes#deprecated-remote-module) in Electron 12 as the linked doc indicates. I haven't yet used the method it recommends so I can't speak to any issues with that.

---

The remote module is deprecated in Electron 12, and will be removed in
Electron 14. It is replaced by the @electron/remote module.

```
// Deprecated in Electron 12:
const { BrowserWindow } = require('electron').remote

// Replace with:
const { BrowserWindow } = require('@electron/remote')

// In the main process:
require('@electron/remote/main').initialize()
```

Comment: Okay new found knowledge....i need to use .remote? okay . btw , i dont use the dialog code in the main process its in a separate js file